# jQuery Sortable connectWith but preserve initial order on second list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery sortable with connectWith to move items from list A to list B. List A has several items (100+). List B only has 15 items (numbered 1-15). I want list B to be sortable but when dragging items from List A, items want to go to the top with a quick drag. Ie if if I grab an item in list A and that items is below list B (before sorting) it wants to be placed in position 1.

I want to maintain the original order in this case. So if I drag something without sorting/positioning, it defaults to the end of the list.

I feel like I need to work with 'start' and 'drop', since start immediately causes the list to shift down when dragging.

Here is my JS

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function(event, ui) {
          var order = $("#sortable2").sortable("toArray");
          $('#selected').val(order.join(","));
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            if ($("#sortable2").sortable("toArray").length > 15) {
                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                swal("You can only select 15!", "", "error");
            }

        }
     }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. without it, we can't answer your question we have no idea what is `swal`, what is the css in play etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with:

```
 helper: 'clone',
```